# How to correctly fill the array before calling AdapterFragment? java

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

I get the information from retrofit from a file and fill the array in the Activity in OnCreate. After creating the fragment and setting it up, the program crashes (in getItemCount) and writes that the array is empty and doesn't understand what I want to output. How can I fill the array before the Adapter class of the snippet is initialized?

Method for filling data into an array

```
       public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Example examples = response.body();
            for(int i = 0; i < examples.getResponse().size(); i++){
                String f_name = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getfName();
                String l_name = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getlName();
                String birthday = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getBirthday();
                String SpecName = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getSpecialty()
                        .iterator().next().getName();
                String SpecId =  response.body().getResponse().iterator().next().getSpecialty()
                        .iterator().next().getSpecialtyId().toString();
                String AvatarUrl = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getAvatrUrl();
                workerList.add(new Worker(f_name, l_name, birthday, SpecName, SpecId, AvatarUrl));

            }
            CurrectName(workerList);
            NewDataFormat(workerList);

        }
```

A piece of code in the Fragment Adaptor

```
public class dataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<dataAdapter.dataViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Worker> workerList;

    public dataAdapter(Context context, List<Worker> workerList){
        this.context = context;
        this.workerList = workerList;
    }

    @Override
    public dataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_data_fragment, parent, false);
        return new dataViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(dataAdapter.dataViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.FName.setText(workerList.get(position).getFname());
        holder.LName.setText(workerList.get(position).getLname());
        holder.Age.setText(workerList.get(position).getAge());
        if (workerList.get(position).getAvatarUrl() != ""){
            Picasso.with(context).load(workerList.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageView);
        } else {
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageView);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return workerList.size();
    }
```

Here's the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.applast.FirstFrame.dataAdapter.getItemCount(dataAdapter.java:52)
```

*Note:*
I'm weak in Android programming, so it would be nice if you could explain what follows in detail

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in adapter classs

```
List<Worker> workerList = new List<Worker>()
setList(List<Worker> workerList){
  workerList.clear(); 
  workerList.addAll(workerList);
  notifyDataSetchanged();
}
```

hope it may help you to prevent crash also and update your adapter list when you available the list of response.also you can try this way in activity class to initialize the list before use it and update it later.

Comment: So create a class in adapter? and for some reason I don't want to initialize `notifyDataSetchanged()`